# Reconnect to existing chat room using asmack library in Android

Tags: android, asmack

**I am reconnecting to existing chat room using following code ..**

```
try {
    mucChat = new MultiUserChat(connection,groupname+"@conference.serviceName");
    DiscussionHistory history = new DiscussionHistory();
        history.setMaxStanzas(30);
    mucChat.join("username", "password", history, SmackConfiguration.getPacketReplyTimeout());
    } catch (XMPPException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

But I am not able to get the history...  am getting `ClassCastException` at:

```
 @Override
 public void processPacket(final Packet packet) {
                final Message message = (Message) packet;
 }
```

throwing exception:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.jivesoftware.smack.packet.Presence cannot be cast to org.jivesoftware.smack.packet.Message
```

Comment: Try cleaning the project.

Comment: I tried that...@UncaughtException...but the issue is when i reconnect to existing room second time after the app starts.....its fine when i reconnect for the first time when app starts....